# modelmultiplechoicefield django return queryset

Tags: python, django

```
Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Vehicle: BMW>]>": "VehicleBattery.vehicle" must be a "Vehicle" instance.
```

**When form submit send upside define error so how can handle this query set in django**

this is form.py code

```
class VehicleBatteryForm(forms.ModelForm):
vehicle = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Vehicle.objects.all())
class Meta:
    model = VehicleBattery
    fields =('vehicle')
```

this is view.py code

```
bform = VehicleBatteryForm(request.POST)
print bform
    if bform.is_valid:
        print "*********if***************"
        bform.save()
    else:
        print "*********else*************"
```

model.py

```
class VehicleBattery(models.Model):
vehicle = models.ForeignKey('Vehicle', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='vehicle', blank= True, null =True)
battery = models.ForeignKey('Battery', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='battery', blank=True, null = True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'VehicleBattery'
```

Comment: Can you share the `VehicleBattery` model? Did you by any change redefined `Vehicle` to another model?

Comment: Also, please correct the syntax in your bold statement, I can't seem to understand what you wanna say.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem update model as per your requirement.. so help me

Comment: Why you are using `ModelMultipleChoiceField`? instead use `ModelChoiceField`

Comment: Try to check out this doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships in your case you need ```ModelChoiceField``` to handle one object.

Comment: Since this is a `ForeignKey`, you can (at most) select *one* vehicle*, so it should be a `ModelChiceField`.

Comment: @Kaushal  i store in db multiple vehicle so i use ModelMultipleChoiceField

Comment: @juliansalas ok thanks

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i select at a time multiple value so

Comment: @chetanghadawaje: then you need a `ManyToManyField`, *not* a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ok i change it